# What is the difference between envoy.filters.http.ext_authz and envoy.ext_authz?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I have been using Envoy within the context of Istio and have been configuring the [external authorization](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/security/ext_authz_filter#arch-overview-ext-authz) filter to offload service authorisation to the Istio mesh.

My understanding is that when configuring Envoy `envoy.filters.http.ext_authz` and `envoy.ext_authz` are synonymous, but is this true?

One possibility I was thinking is that `envoy.ext_authz` is a short name that only works when the context of the configuration implies the filter is an HTTP filter, but I have not found any evidence for this.

Reading through the Envoy documentation I have only seen the filter referred to by the full `envoy.filters.http.ext_authz` name (for example [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/ext_authz_filter#config-http-filters-ext-authz)), so relevant documentation or code would be useful to show (or not show) the equivalence of the two names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have deprecated envoy.ext_authz filter name since v1.14.0 version. After v1.14.0 they use **envoy.filters.http** prefix for Http filters and **envoy.filters.network** prefix for network filters. You can see all the deprecated name list from here. https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/version_history/v1.14.0#deprecated